# Filter list of old bookmark URLs to exclude websites no longer in service using Vim

Tags: curl, url, sed, vim, grep

I'm trying to learn some more about Vim and the Linux command line; the project I'm working on is:

Trying to convert a browser's export of `bookmarks.html` into a plain text list of URLs ***that still work.***

---

1. First, I used `lynx -dump -listonly bookmarks.html > bookmarks` to format the HTML to plain text:

```
   1. https://example.com/vim-is-cool.html
   2. https://example.com/index.html
```

3. Used Vim to strip the numbers and leading spaces away (`:% s/.\+ /`)
4. Used Vim to remove everything but the top level domain (`:%! cut -d'/' -f1,2,3`)
5. Used Vim to remove duplicates with `:sort u`
6. To test one of the links, I'd use:

```
curl -I https://www.example.com | grep HTTP | sed 's/HTTP\/1\.1 //g'
200 OK
```

Now, I'd like to:

7. Check the shortlist of short URLs via the same command (I'm not sure how to iterate the same command for every line in Vim's buffer)
8. Filter the file containing all full URLs based on whether cURL gets a 200 OK for the short URL (this part is also way beyond me)
9. Write the remaining list of working full URLs to `bookmarks4` (most likely I could handle this)

If reasonably possible, I'd like to complete all of that without scripting in shell/bash or leaving Vim.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (all GNU utilities using bash):

```
lynx -dump -listonly bookmarks.html |
grep -o 'https\?://[^/]*' |
sort -u |
parallel -k 'curl -I -m2 {} |& grep -q "HTTP/[0-9.]\+ 200" && echo {}' >bookmarks4
```

Use lynx to format links.

Use grep to format urls.

Use sort to sort and remove duplicates.

Use parallel to check the urls using curl and checking its output for a 200 reply using grep. Output those urls that meet the requirements to bookmarks4.

To output the original urls, perhaps:

```
lynx -dump -listonly bookmarks.html |
grep http |
parallel --rpl '{url} s:.*(https?.*):$1:' \
         --rpl '{dom} s:.*(https?\://[^/]*).*:$1:' \
        'curl -m2 -I {dom} |& grep -q "HTTP/[0-9.]\+ 200" && echo {url}' |
sort -u >bookmarks4
```

Comment: This works great up until the parallel command; I get no output from parallel with my own bookmark file or (just for a sanity check) the ones listed in: https://gist.github.com/demersdesigns/4442cd84c1cc6c5ccda9b19eac1ba52b

Comment: @swishkin I amended the curl and grep commands to cater for time outs and different headers.

Comment: Great! So, now, the commands produce a file containing only the top level domains (`https://www.youtube.com`, for instance), but not the full original bookmarks that match those working top level domains. Do you have any idea why that would be?

Comment: @swishkin I would guess some did not return 200 or timedout.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding me; I'm looking for the final product to be a list of the original full URLs (e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067844`), but only those original full URLs for which the top level domain (e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com/`) is reachable when cURL checks for it. If `https://stackoverflow.com/` returned anything but HTTP 200 OK, then `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067844` should not appear in the final file, but if `https://stackoverflow.com/` returns 200 OK, then `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067844` should appear.